# Things are getting enqueued in sidekiq but not executing in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

So after a user signs up, I am doing two things

1) Sending a welcome email
2) Updating their facebook profile pic to my s3

```
  if user.save

    UpdateAvatarWorker.perform_async(user.id)


    UserMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver_later unless user.email.nil?

    render json: {

      status: 200
    }
  else
    render json: { errors: user.errors.messages, status: 500 }
  end
```

Now in the sidekiq web UI I see that these jobs are getting enqueued but not scheduled

Here are my configurations

`config/sidekiq.yml`

```
development:
  :concurrency: 5
production:
  :concurrency: 10
```

`config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`

```
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/web'

if Rails.env.production?

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { size: 2 }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { size: 10 }
  end

end
```

`Procfile`

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -v -t 25 -q default -q mailers
```

`config/initializers/redis.rb`

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV['REDISTOGO_URL']) || "redis://localhost:6379/"
REDIS = Redis.new(url: uri)
```

I am using mini plan in heroku redis go which has 50 connections to redis

`redistogo (redistogo-objective-72231)          mini         $9/month  created
 └─ as REDISTOGO`

The worker always seems to be in crash mode

```
➜  couch_bunny git:(master) heroku ps --app couchbunny
=== run: one-off processes (1)
run.9503 (Standard-1X): up 2018/03/31 17:20:00 +0530 (~ 41m ago): rails console

=== web (Standard-1X): bundle exec rails server -p $PORT (1)
web.1: up 2018/03/31 17:31:03 +0530 (~ 30m ago)

=== worker (Standard-1X): bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -v -t 25 -q default -q mailers (1)
worker.1: crashed 2018/03/31 17:47:20 +0530 (~ 14m ago)
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like sidekiq is not running. Could you check if it is running ? OK it isn;t because it is crashed. You could always check the logs.

Comment: Hey @GorillaApe how do I check if it's running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're manually setting a pool size of `10` via `Sidekiq.configure_server` and you're starting Sidekiq with a concurrency of `10`. Internally, Sidekiq requires the pool to have at least `concurrency + 2` connections, so that's where the error comes from.

[Mike suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38295160/384293) to don't set the `size` option manually but to let Sidekiq do it. For a concurrency of `10` it will automatically set the pool size to `10 + 5 = 15`.

Comment: so I can remove the configure_server block altogether?

Comment: Yes, as you're not configuring anything else in it, you can simply remove it.